# If $f$ is continuous, then $G$ is connected . True/false?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, continuity, compactness, connectedness

Let  $X$ be  a compact topological space   and let $f : X \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$  be  a function  . The  graph  $f$ is the   set $G =  \{ (x, f(x)  )  : x   \in  X \}  \subseteq   X \times \mathbb{R}$

My   question  is that  Is the  following statement is True/false  ?

If $f$  is  continuous, then  $G$  is  connected

My attempt  : I think   yes, because  the continuous image  of a connected set is connected.

Comment: you should at least assume that $X$ is connected.

Comment: @Thomas   compact  implies  connected    here  already  given that  X  be  a  compact  topological space

Comment: nonsense: a finite metric space is compact but not connected. The Cantor set too. Or $[0,1] \cup \{2\}$ etc..

Comment: @jasmine Compact most definitely does not imply connected, not even by a long shot.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma  sir   u r  right     i forget  the  example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, it is false. If, for instance, $X=\{0,1\}$, endowed with the discrete topology, then $X$ is compact, but $G$ is always disconnected.

Of course, the statement holds if $X$ is connected, even without assuming compactness.

Answer (score 2):

False, and compactness is a red herring. We need $X$ to be connected.

It's clear that $G$ is homeomorhic to $X$ when $f$ is continuous (the first projection is the continuous inverse and when $f$ is continuous, so is the map
$F: x \to (x, f(x))$ and $G=F[X]$).